# Trying to send a adress as a parameter

Tags: python, pygame

## Intro

I'm having a very hard time on my first game, all of that because i dont know how to send an path as an argument that can be referenced.
Onto the problem, i have this Text class that does everything text related.

```
class Text:
textfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 20)
# this is the place where text obects are stored at
textcount = 0
textwheel = []


# this is a method that receives arguments and creates a text object out of them
# that object is put inside the list above
@staticmethod
def createtext(text, posx, posy):
    Text.textwheel.append(Text.textcount)
    Text.textwheel[Text.textcount] = Text(text, posx, posy)
    Text.textcount += 1

# path and text are almost the same thing
# path is supposed to hold the actual path to the object i want to reference every frame
# whilst text is the actual text version that is to be displayed
def __init__(self, text, posx, posy):
    self.path = text
    self.text = str(self.path)
    self.texposx = posx
    self.texposy = posy
    self.surface = Text.textfont.render(self.text, True, (0, 0, 0))

# every frame a function runs through the list and updates the text to be the str version of the path
@staticmethod
def txtupd():
    for textnum in Text.textwheel:
        textnum.text = str(textnum.path)
        textnum.surface = Text.textfont.render(textnum.text, True, (0, 0, 0))
        Window.window.blit(textnum.surface, (textnum.texposx, textnum.texposy))
```

The problem is, when i try and create an object  with certain arguments, it doesnt send a path, it sends just a value instead, Example:

```
    # player input
    Text.createtext(Input.playerinput, 50, 50)
    Text.createtext(' W  S  A  D', 50, 20)
    # player cordinates
    Text.createtext(Player.playerwheel[0].posx, 500, 20)
    Text.createtext(Player.playerwheel[0].posy, 500, 50)
```

here i ask it to create texts with the current player input (list), and the player cordinates (x and y both ints), the thing is, when i send it the player cordinates (int), it just gets that value and keeps referencing that, contrary to when i send it the playerinput list, that one gets dinamically referenced and updated every frame.

here are the playerinput together with the player cords

```
class Input:
    playerinput = [False, False, False, False]

class Player:
    playercount = 0
    playerwheel = []

    @staticmethod
    def createplayer():
        Player.playerwheel.append(Player.playercount)
        Player.playerwheel[Player.playercount] = Player()
        Player.playercount += 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.posx = 200
        self.posy = 200
        self.spdx = 0
        self.spdy = 0
        self.color = (0, 0, 0)
```

I just want to be able to send paths to variables so that they can keep being referenced dinamically and be updated accordingly.

whole code in case u want to mess with it(you'll need the pygame library doe):

https://pastebin.com/aEaWaYmW

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Comment: Are you looking for [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str)? e.g.: `Text.createtext(  str(Player.playerwheel[0].posx)  , 500, 20)`

Comment: @0x5453 had to go through a lot of reading, and also figure out a different sollution entirelly, but you certainly did send me towards the right path to solve it all, thankya.

Comment: PLEASE fix your code indenting